# Is there a way I can mark an item/event in the default Calendar app as "DONE" or "ACCOMPLISHED"?

Tags: macos, calendar

For example, I want to take track whether I have finished something or not, is there a way how to mark that something was finished/accomplished/done?

Now I only see when something should had happened but I have no idea if I really did it or how was the outcome, etc.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: You might want to set those sort of events in the Reminders.app not Calendar

Comment: So, it is not possible in the default Calendar app, based on your answer's approach. Perhaps the inability to have both events and tasks is a problem. I probably need a more advanced "pricier" calendar app ;D

Comment: Before you go that far - what does Reminders not supply? Also going forward do you need more as what you are asking for might be more project planning so OmniPlan might be an idea but it provides a lot more than you are currently asking for.

Comment: Calendar apps basically are schedulers (what will happen when), so keeping track of things to be done *anytime* is not something any calendar application is good at by default. You might get better answers if you describe your workflow and what you want to accomplish instead of focusing on the specific tool already.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the (lack of) requirements in your question I can think of multiple ways of marking something as done in the Calendar app:

- Create a new calendar called "DONE" and move events you've completed there. You can then optionally show that calendar in a different colour.
- Write the word "[DONE]" in the title of the event once you've completed it (or any other unique term). I believe you can even use emoji's like a ✅, you can open the emoji panel with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.
- Add a note to the event indicating that it's done. Here you can also add how the event went.

Comment: I like the combination of 1 and 3. Using a new calendar means you can hide the done events (unlike option 2) and updating the note before you do so leaves you with a nice paper trail of what you did and how it went.